# Laravel migration - change column structure

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, migration

I have a column `img` in my `news` table and I want to change the structure. Currently it's set to `varchar (200)` and I want to be `text`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So did you fix it or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either drop the column and create it again or use `DB::statement` and manually write the query to alter table. From what I remember Laravel does not provide the way to alter column values.

Comment: You could put at least some effort to this answer and write the query by yourself. The answer above is the correct one if you are that lazy.

Comment: I agree. Even though the answer you referred to is my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE news MODIFY COLUMN img TEXT');
}

public function down()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE news MODIFY COLUMN img VARCHAR(200)');
}
```